# Javascript array itself turns undefined whilst iterating over it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm doing some javascript challenges on codeschool.com.
Whilst at the function expressions chapter, I came across the following weird bug.

In the following script - which can be heavily refactored, I know - the 'queue' variable gets assigned a value of 'undefined' after the second run.

First iteration:

1. queue array printed, containing 4 elements
2. "hello 1" printed

Second iteration:

1. queue array printed, containing 3 elements
2. "hello 3" printed
3. queue array printed, containing 2 elements

Third iteration - where the bug(?) occurs:

1. undefined is printed - instead of the queue array which should still contain 2 elements

First I thought something was wrong at codeschool's end, but after trying to run the code in chrome's dev tools I got the same results.
As far as I can tell nothing asynchronous should be happening which could mess anything up?

```
var puzzlers = [
  function(a) { return 8 * a - 10; },
  function(a) { return (a - 3) * (a - 3) * (a - 3); },
  function(a) { return a * a + 4; },
  function(a) { return a % 5; }
];
var start = 2;

var applyAndEmpty = function(input, queue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
    alert(queue);
    if (i === 0) {
      alert("hello 1");
      var output = queue.shift()(input);
    } else if (queue.length === 1) {
      alert("hello 2");
      return queue.shift()(output);
    } else {
      alert("hello 3");
      output = queue.shift()(output);
      alert(queue);
    }
  }
};

alert(applyAndEmpty(start, puzzlers));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code Review**

There's a couple bad things happening in this code; we should go over them first. For convenience's sake, I'm going to replace all `alert` calls with `console.log` calls – The console is much nicer for debugging things.

OK the first problem is you're using `queue.shift()` inside a `for` loop. `Array.prototype.shift` will change the length of the array, so you're not meant to use this inside a loop (outside of a very specialized case).

So each time we loop, `i` goes up one and `queue.length` goes down one – the two values are converging on each other which means you'll never actually touch all the values in `queue`

---

**Refactor**

We can fix that with a very simple adjustment of your function – remove the `for` loop! `queue.shift()` is effectively incrementing for us, but removing one element at a time. All we need to do is check if `queue.length` is empty – if so, we're done, *otherwise* `shift` one item off the queue and repeat

```js
var applyAndEmpty = function(input, queue) {
  console.log(input)
  if (queue.length === 0)
    return input;
  else
    return applyAndEmpty(queue.shift()(input), queue)
}

var puzzlers = [
  function(a) { return 8 * a - 10; },
  function(a) { return (a - 3) * (a - 3) * (a - 3); },
  function(a) { return a * a + 4; },
  function(a) { return a % 5; }
];
var start = 2;

console.log(applyAndEmpty(start, puzzlers));
// [initial input]               2
// 8 * 2 - 10                  = 6
// (6 - 3) * (6 - 3) * (6 - 3) = 27
// 27 * 27 + 4                 = 733
// 733 % 5                     = 3
// [final output]              = 3
console.log(puzzlers); // []
```

---

**Greater lesson**

There's one important thing to know about stepping thru arrays manually. You do **ONE** of the options below

**1. check that the array is empty before attempting to get a value**

```
// there are no items so we cannot get one
if (arr.length === 0)
  doSomething;
// we know there is at least one item, so it is safe to get one
else
  doOtherThing( arr.shift() )
```

**2. null-check the thing you attempted to get**

```
x = queue.shift();
// we didn't get a value, queue must've been empty
if (x === undefined)
  doSomething

// yay we got something, we can use x now
else
  doOtherThing( x )
```

It's your personal choice to use one over the other, tho I generally dislike null-checks of this kind. I believe it's better to check that the array has the value before attempting to grab it.

Doing **BOTH** of these options would be a logical error. If we check the array has a length of non-0, we can deduce we have an x – therefore we don't have to null-check for an x.

---

**Remarks**

I don't know if this was for an assignment or whatever, but you basically wrote up function composition from scratch – tho this is a kind of special *destructive* composition.

It seems you're aware of the destructive nature because you've named your function `applyAndEmpty`, but just in case you didn't know that was necessary, I'll share a non-destructive example below.

```js
var lcompose = function(fs) {
  return function (x) {
    if (fs.length === 0)
      return x
    else
      return lcompose(fs.slice(1))(fs[0](x))
  }
}

var puzzlers = [
  function(a) { return 8 * a - 10; },
  function(a) { return (a - 3) * (a - 3) * (a - 3); },
  function(a) { return a * a + 4; },
  function(a) { return a % 5; }
];

var start = 2;

console.log(lcompose(puzzlers)(start)) // 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation! However, as I also commented on another answer, I just realised myself I'm mutating the length of my array. I can't think of a reason how I missed this. Probably due to the fact I've mostly been using the functional paradigm for the past few months in which mutation of anything is never the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Accepting your answer as you explained it so well.

Comment: @JasperCatthoor happy to help. In the future, if you want a really quick & easy way to run JS code and get a result, I highly recommend [repl.it/js](https://repl.it/languages/javascript) (for native JS) or [repl.it/babel](https://repl.it/languages/babel) (for ES6+)

Comment: This answer is a paragon of quality.

Answer (score 1):

That `undefined` you're getting is coming from this `alert()` call:

```
alert(applyAndEmpty(start, puzzlers));
```

At the end of the second iteration, `i` will be `1` and the queue length will be `2`. Thus `i` is incremented for the next iteration, and the loop condition no longer holds — `i` is 2, and no longer less than the queue length.

It's a good habit when debugging to include some messaging instead of just values so that you can tell one debug output line from another. It's also a good idea to use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`.

Comment: Yup, I really just noticed I'm mutating the length of the array over which I'm iterating. How did I not see this earlier - sigh.

The alert statements are due to codeschool not displaying my log statements correctly, thanks for the tip anyhow :)

Answer (score 1):

Assume the below solves your problem.

- You used queue.length in second condition, at that stage, you perform only one shift and expecting a 4 size queue to be of 2 size, it is one error.

```js
var puzzlers = [
  function(a) { return 8 * a - 10; },
  function(a) { return (a - 3) * (a - 3) * (a - 3); },
  function(a) { return a * a + 4; },
  function(a) { return a % 5; }
];
var start = 2;

var applyAndEmpty = function(input, queue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      alert("hello 1");
      var output = queue.shift()(input);
    } else if (i === 1) {
      alert("hello 2");
      return queue.shift()(output);
    } else {
      alert("hello 3");
      output = queue.shift()(output);
    }
  }
};

alert(applyAndEmpty(start, puzzlers));
```

Comment: Yes, as I commented on the previous two answers, I had just found out this stupid mistake myself. Thanks for your answer though!